# Exchange 2010 Redirect OWA http to https (was working, stopped after upgrading SSL cert)

Tags: iis, exchange, exchange-2010, redirect, outlook-web-app

I have a CAS server with a redirect for http://mail.contoso.com to https://mail.contoso.com/owa. Which was working great, but we upgraded our cert to a SAN and imported that, and while everything else works as expected, the redirect does not work anymore and goes to a 403.

Did I miss a checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Open IIS Manager, select Default Web Site, and open HTTP Redirect. Is the "Redirect requests to this destination" checkbox checked, with https://mail.contoso.com/owa in the box? I also have both checkboxes below it checked, and am using a 301 redirect.